# Why won't the quotation marks and dash be shown correctly?

Tags: punctuation

I tried to write a document having a dash after a quotation mark. However, pdflatex has problems to show the document correctly. It looks like the second quotation mark is missing and the second dash is too short and there is an extra hyphen.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
a --- b --- "a" --- b
\end{document}
```

The following seems to work corretly but I'm not sure if it is a proper way to solve the problem:

```
a --- b --- "a"\,\! --- b
```

Comment: You should never use `"` for quotes. A double opening quote is `\`\``, while a double closing quote is `''` (two apostrophes).

Comment: Like Danish, Finnish makes `"` active so it has a special meaning, kind of like an extra ``\``. In Danish we can use it to type `"-` to get a hyphen that allows hyphenation in the compound word. I assume the Finnish setup is similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quotes should be produced with

```
``a''
```

or, as you use UTF-8

```
“a”
```

but *never* with the undirected quotes, particularly using `babel`, which makes `"` a shorthand prefix for Finnish. So you want either

```
a --- b --- ``a'' --- b
```

or

```
a --- b --- “a” --- b
```